# Can i use PnP core sdk inside .net 8.0 console application and use AD App registration which uses self-signed certificate

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, pnp, console-application

I have created a AD app registration which uses self-signed certificate for authentication. and i grant the AD app registration full control on SharePoint and graph APIs.

Now I want to build a .NET 8.0 console application which run on schedule bases. so can i use PnP core SDK with AD app that uses self-signed certificate to interact with SharePoint online lists and libraries? if this is possible, then is there a sample code that can help me?

Thanks